# Define instance to target group in ALB from ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm designing a cloud solution to a web-service. I need have a ALB which listens to 443 port and by a ALB, do forward traffic to the same instance in different ports.

I created the 2 target groups with different ports, I created the ALB with a listener and 2 listener rules pointing to target groups.

The instance is created by autoscaling group, with 1 desire instance.
But my doubt now is how can I assign this instance to this target group. If I did by hand, all its ok, but the problem is that I'm doing by Cloudformation. And I don't know how to refer the result instance of this autoscaling group, also created by CF.

I was reading AWS documentation but I didn't find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: target groups are referenced on [autoscaling group level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns). See `TargetGroupARNs` property

Comment: @MolecularMan Thanks for reply. But i dont understand the behavior.. In my enviroment i have 2 target groups created to different webapps, so i have to reference both in the ASG?

Comment: If you want the both webapps to be hosted within the same ASG, then yes, reference both. If you want to have separate ASG for each webapp, every ASG would have to reference separate target group.